# Load last quote

Tags: magento2, product, quote

is that possible to load the last quote of the logged customer to get all product from this quote and add them into cart ?

I want to to this directly from front end, so i'll probably add a button on a page

Here's my code so far :

```
                $collection = $this->collection->create();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerId);
//        echo "<pre>".print_r($collection->getLastItem()->getData(), true)."</pre>"; //show data of last quote
        $quoteId = $collection->getLastItem()->getData('entity_id'); //get id of last quote
        echo "quote id : " . $quoteId;

        $quote = $this->_quoteRepository->get($quoteId);
        $products = $quote->getItemsCollection()->getData();
//        echo "<pre>".print_r($products, true)."</pre>"; //show data of last quote

        $productsRenew = array();
        foreach($products as $product){
            $productsRenew[] = array(
              'product_id' => $product['product_id'],
                'qty' => $product['qty'],
                'price' => $product['price'],
                'sku' => $product['sku'],
                'name' => $product['name'],
            );
        }
        echo "<pre>".print_r($productsRenew, true)."</pre>"; //show items data
```

EDIT : how can I add multiple product to cart in one time ? To do this product by product, I used this  :

```
    public function getAddToCartPostParams($product)
{
    return $this->listProductBlock->getAddToCartPostParams($product);
}
```

But I don't think this will work, maybe there's another way to achieve this ?

Comment: If order is placed for last quote then the quote will be deactivated. You need to reactivate it. also $collection->getLastItem()->getData('entity_id'); line will not return the quote id, this will return item id.

Comment: I've made some changes, now I get my products from the last quote, see my updated post

Comment: Great so issue  has been resolved?

Comment: In a way, I still need to add products item of last quote to cart

Comment: So you are getting the last quote? Right?

Comment: Yes I get the last quote. I'll create a new topic for the next part, thanks :)

Comment: Can you check my answer?